Question about homology of k[x]
I want to compute $Tor_1^A(k,k)$, where A = k[x],k - algebraically closed field. I know how to compute Tor functor through Koszul resolution, but I want to do it strictly through tensoring bar resolution with k, I have $k\otimes A \otimes A \otimes k \to_f k\otimes A \otimes k \to_g k$ so I need to find $\frac{Ker(g)}{Im(f)}$, but I find out that
$\frac{Ker(g)}{Im(f)} = 0$ for every $k_1 \otimes f(x)\otimes k_2$, I can take $k_1\otimes 1 \otimes f(x) \otimes k_2$, so $d(k_1\otimes 1 \otimes f(x) \otimes k_2) = k_1 \otimes f(x)\otimes k_2$  which I guess is not true, I thought it must be $\frac{Ker(g)}{Im(f)} = k$. Augmentation is $k[x] \to \frac{k[x]}{(x)}$, so polynomials act trivial on k. Any hints would be appreciated.

I'm not familiar with "bar resolution"...  My approach would be to take the free resolution $\cdots 0 \to 0 \to A \overset{x}\to A$ of $k$, tensor with $k$, and take $H^1$.
